# Why the argument that preg_replace_callback passes to the callback function is an array

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-replace-callback

This might be a stupid question but why [`preg_replace_callback`](https://www.php.net/preg_replace_callback) puts every match in a single-element array and passes it to the callback function so I have to use `$matches[0]` to process a match, why doesn't it pass matches to the callback function as strings?

Comment: @Brewal I do have multiple matches and for all those multiple matches the callback function receives an array with a single element in it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you can have capturing groups, and each element in the array would be what the capturing group captured. The element at index 0 is always the entire match.

For example, given a regex that matches `MM/DD/YYYY` dates, you might put each segment of the date in its own capturing group, perhaps something naive like this:

```
(\d{2})/(\d{2})/(\d{4})
```

Then, you'd have a matches array similar to:

```
[0] - MM/DD/YYYY
[1] - MM
[2] - DD
[3] - YYYY
```

Comment: @DesmondHume - No, [they're in there](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.subpatterns.php), you just have to dig.

Comment: Wonder why they decided not to tell anything about capturing groups on the preg_replace_callback's page

Comment: @DesmondHume - Probably because it's not specific to just `preg_replace_callback()` - It's a general feature of regex and all of the PCRE functions. `preg_match()`, `preg_match_all()`, etc. all benefit from this feature.